# ZSH equivalent to Bash 'read' command for selecting user output

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh

I'm trying to translate a bash script into zsh. Mostly got it cracked, except for this portion:

```
for i in ${!gresults[@]} do
  echo $i ${gresults[$i]}  
done            
read user_pick
```

I get a `parse error near read`, which isn't helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: `read` is not the culprit. Missing `;` and lots of `"`. https://www.shellcheck.net FTW

Comment: The missing quotes are not relevant to the parse error; the missing `;` absolutely is.

Comment: In addition to your syntax problems, bear in mind that the zsh `read` is similar, but not identical to the bash `read`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like that:

```
for i in "${!gresults[@]}";
do
  echo "$i ${gresults[$i]}";
done;
read user_pick;
```

Comment: For cleanliness: You could get rid of all semicolons in your code.